# Implementing Async Task in a Class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httpclient

I have tried making a class supporting AsyncTask and I failed miserably. Later I made a superclass of this class and added to my Main Class this:

```
//subclass of the superclass CustomHttpClient
CustomHttpClient2 cl= new CustomHttpClient2();
cl.execute();
response = cl.executeHttpPost("http://ironis.dyndns.org/aeglea/android/log.php", postParameters);
```

The error message is android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

The class I want to convert is this(I used it in sdk 7, but I moved to 14 and now it fails)

```
public class CustomHttpClient2 (extends CustomHttpClient)<<I used it without this {

 public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds
    private static HttpClient mHttpClient;


    /**
     * Get our single instance of our HttpClient object.
     *
     * @return an HttpClient object with connection parameters set
     */
    private static HttpClient getHttpClient() {
        if (mHttpClient == null) {
            mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            final HttpParams params = mHttpClient.getParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
            ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        }
        return mHttpClient;
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP Post request to the specified url with the
     * specified parameters.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @param postParameters The parameters to send via the request
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public JSONObject executeHttpPost(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        HttpEntity he=null;
        JSONObject jo=null;

        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
            UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
            request.setEntity(formEntity);
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            //mine
            he=response.getEntity();
            jo=new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(he));
            //end mine

            return jo;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Performs an HTTP GET request to the specified url.
     *
     * @param url The web address to post the request to
     * @return The result of the request
     * @throws Exception
     */
    public static String executeHttpGet(String url) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            HttpClient client = getHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
            request.setURI(new URI(url));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
            String line = "";
            String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + NL);
            }
            in.close();

            String result = sb.toString();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (in != null) {
                try {
                    in.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The other class I use CustomHttpClient is below

```
public class CustomHttpClient extends AsyncTask<HttpClient,String,String> {
public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds
private static HttpClient mHttpClient;



protected HttpClient doInBackground(String... params) {
    if (mHttpClient == null) {
        mHttpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        final HttpParams params1 = mHttpClient.getParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params1, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params1, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
        ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params1, HTTP_TIMEOUT);
    }
    return mHttpClient;
}



@Override
protected String doInBackground(HttpClient... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}




}
```

Any love for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoever has a similar problem I will post my solution.

I modded the @sandrstar 's solution and I did that

```
public class CustomHttpTask extends AsyncTask<Object,String,JSONObject> {
   public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds
   private JSONObject response = null;

   @Override
   protected JSONObject doInBackground(Object... params) {
       //subclass of the superclass CustomHttpClient
       //CustomHttpClient cl= (CustomHttpClient) params[0];
       String url = (String) params[0];
       ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = (ArrayList<NameValuePair>) params[1];
    try {
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(url, postParameters);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        // say, you need response string back

        return response;
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {

    }
    public JSONObject getval(){
        return response;
    }

}
```

Now I can do multiple posts in different url's. The problem is that I want a json object. There are 2 ways. Either create a function as I did. or use AsyncTask's get() function

```
CustomHttpTask asdf = new CustomHttpTask();
response = asdf.execute("http://192.168.1.4/aeglea/android/log.php", postParameters).get();
```

That executes first and when it finishes it executes the get part. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Probably Your async task would look like:

```
public class CustomHttpTask extends AsyncTask<CustomHttpClient2,String,String> {
   public static final int HTTP_TIMEOUT = 30 * 1000; // milliseconds


   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(HttpClient... params) {
       //subclass of the superclass CustomHttpClient
       CustomHttpClient2 cl= params[0];
       response = cl.executeHttpPost("http://ironis.dyndns.org/aeglea/android/log.php", postParameters);

        // say, you need response string back

        return response.toString();
}

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " response");
    }
}
```

And call it the following way:

```
CustomHttpTask task = new CustomHttpTask();
task.execute(new CustomHttpClient2());
```

And, Android is doing the right way throwing NetworkOnMainThreadException then You try to execute network requests on UI Thread to help You avoid ANR with slow connections.

Comment: +1 for nice answer, but should remove this line: **cl.execute();**

Comment: @sandrstar I took what you said and modified it a little. You are the man, man. :P

Answer (score 0):

I would think it might have something to do with not overriding the correct `doInBackground` method. Instead, you're overloading with different param types. Switch the HttpClient and String in your class definition (e.g. `...extends AsyncTask<String,String,HTTPClient>`) to be able to pass the correct params and return the proper result.

[EDIT] I'm not sure if I understood the essence of your question, but my point was the only stuff that will be executed in a separate thread (which you must put your IO in) is the stuff in the correct `doInBackground` method.